# Is it necessary to have a failure handler for google wallet?

Tags: html, android-pay

Is the failure handler moreso optional or mandatory? Google seems to handle all notification to the end user whether their purchase was successful or not and if not, why, so apart from giving my own error message is there anything else I would want to do inside my failure handler? What is the consequence of simply declaring an empty function as my failure handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The success and failure client handlers for the Walet for digital goods API are used to return control back to the application after the in-app transaction has completed.

If the failure handler is called, the app should NOT give the user access to the digital good or content that the user tried to purchase. You can check the returned error code for the reason the transaction failed and give the user a customized error message:

https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/jsreference#failurehandler

OTOH, if the success handler is called the app SHOULD give the user access to the digital good or content that the user purchased. Before doing that make sure to also check with your server that the server postback was called for this transaction:

https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/postback

Comment: Its still not clear to me if it is necessary to include a failure handler, but this seems to be the best answer I'm going to get...